# Does inotify really work for files or only for directories?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I am trying to use `inotify` for monitoring changes to a file `/dev/hvc0` using the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  (sizeof(struct inotify_event))
#define BUF_LEN     (1024 * (EVENT_SIZE + 16))
#define WATCH_FILE "/dev/hvc0" /* This file should be present
                                  before this program is run */

int main() {
    int notify_fd;
    int length;
    int i = 0;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];
    notify_fd = inotify_init();
    if (notify_fd < 0) {
        perror("inotify_init");
    }
    int wd = inotify_add_watch(notify_fd, WATCH_FILE, IN_MODIFY | IN_ACCESS);
    int length_read = read(notify_fd, buffer, BUF_LEN);
    if (length_read) {
        perror("read");
    }
    while (i < length_read) {
        struct inotify_event *event =
            (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];
        if (event->len) {
            if (event->mask & IN_ACCESS) {
                printf("The file %s was accessed.\n", event->name);
            } else if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
                printf("The file %s was modified.\n", event->name);
            }
        }
    }

    (void) inotify_rm_watch(notify_fd, wd);
    (void) close(notify_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this does not print if the file was accessed/modified. However whenever I change the path to be monitored to a directory and a file was changed, it prints the correct event occurred.

Does `inotify` work for monitoring file changes too? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you again check by just commenting `if (event->len) ` statement for test puspose.

Comment: @JKB: gr8, its working now! But then why is `event->len` 0? o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not understanding why the `event->len` is return zero may be because the file name is not returned. but for only testing purpose you just comment it. And in second point
Your handling of i is broken, you never reset it to 0 in the loop. This causes any later inotify events to be considered only when they are longer than the longest event before them, which is not likely what you want.And please in while loop please put `i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;`

```
int main() {
    int notify_fd;
    int length;
    int i = 0;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];
    notify_fd = inotify_init();
    if (notify_fd < 0) {
        perror("inotify_init");
    }
    int wd = inotify_add_watch(notify_fd, WATCH_FILE, IN_MODIFY | IN_ACCESS);
    while(1)
    {
        length = read( notify_fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );

        if ( length < 0 ) {
          perror( "read" );
        }

        while ( i < length ) 
        {
            struct inotify_event *event =
            (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];
            // if (event->len) {
            if (event->mask & IN_ACCESS) {
                printf("The file %s was accessed.\n", event->name);
            } else if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
                printf("The file %s was modified.\n", event->name);
            }
            // }
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
    }

  ( void ) inotify_rm_watch( notify_fd, wd );
  ( void ) close( notify_fd);

  exit( 0 );
}
```

Comment: The program terminates after a change has been made even if I reset i to 0, I want to continuously monitor for changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to increase `i` . Add this before the end of the loop:

```
i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
```

If you want to monitor the changes you also need to wrap the read / print operation in an endless loop.

Comment: Edited the code and the question as you said(I actually don't need to modify for creation and deletion; only for access/modification) to check for access/modification, still does not print event for files.

Comment: Check my update. I've explained it better. They is, that the path given as a parameter to `inotify_add_watch` must exist in order to make the function work. That's why you can track the creation of a file, only by watching the containing folder

Comment: I actually only need to monitor access/modification, have edited the code and the question, but I don't the event notification for the same.

Comment: The code is working if I comment out ` if (event->len)`, but why is it zero?

Comment: +1 for the very helpful suggestions, commenting out `event->len` solved.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154004/can-inotify-be-used-to-watch-for-a-specific-file-to-be-created-without-monitorin), it appears that Linux does not watch on specific files. If you were to listen to specific files, you should listen to its parent directory first.